# View a theme on wordpress as it is (without your website contents)

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site on my localhost named Creative Architects.
I have applied a theme Twenty Sixteen on the website.
Now I am looking for themes for another website. But when I try to view those themes it applies my website content to the selected theme.

I've searched for this on the official website as well as other websites. They give ways to preview a theme for my wordpress site without activating it on the site.

How do i view a theme as it is, without previewing it with my wordpress site but with how it has been uploaded?

Comment: Go to developer's website. They usually have a live demo preview...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS Jordi Nebot said, you have on developer website option for live preview of themes.

https://wordpress.org/themes/

You select wanted theme, then navigate to top right corner and press **preview**
(as highlighted on picture below)
[image]

I hope that's the answer you were looking for (and if I understand it correctly)